# Dropdown with key input search of elements

Tags: javascript, css, html, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need your valuable suggestions and guidance to help me get out of this tricky situation.

I have a scenario, where I need to build a Dropdown like the below one.

```
<ul class="dropdown">
<li><a href="#">America</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Brazil</a></li>
<li><a href="#">China</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Denmark</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Egypt</a></li>
</ul>
```

The desired functionality is that I should be able to use keyboard input to scroll through the items, lets say i press key "E" on my keyboard it should hover/focus on Egypt.

I realize this functionality cant be achieved using UL>Li, However we can use Select tag to implement this functionality.

```
<select class="dropdown">
<option>America</li>
<option>Brazil</li>
<option>China</li>
<option>Denmark</li>
<option>Egypt</li>
<select>
```

But when we use select tags, we cannot style the dropdown, Especially like CSS padding doesnt work on select tag dropdowns on most broswers.

All I wanna ask Is, How can I build a drop-down with these 3 functionalities :

```
1.Open on Tab key press 
2.Browse listed items using key input. 
3.Style the dropdown for cross broswer compatibility.
```

I did spend ample time in finding a solution for this online, I dint find any perfect solution apart from this plugin

https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

I'd regret to say that I'm not allowed to use any external plugins at work.To achieve this only tools I'm allowed to use is Bootstrap, jQuery, Javascript ,CSS ,HTML and cant use angular.

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: You can try [http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html). Seriously, all the stuff you're looking for is available there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it’s not possible to style a `<select>` dropdown consistently across all browsers. Bootstrap Select and other similar plugins (e.g. Chosen) use JS and custom markup to create a faux `<select>`, which is bad for accessibility (see https://vimeo.com/84970341#t=614s).

Personally, I would use a `<select>` element and live with the default browser styling.

You *can* style the `<select>` toggle itself, though, without hurting accessibility. Just not the dropdown. Here are some examples:

- http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/
- http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/custom-select/

Another option could be to code the countries as a list of links and make it expandable with JS. Just be sure to add the appropriate aria roles.

- http://edenspiekermann.github.io/a11y-toggle/
- http://heydonworks.com/practical_aria_examples/

Comment: Hi Ted, Thanks for your answer ! 
I just wanted to let you know that, I want to use select tags because by default they will enable scrolling through elements using keyboard Input. The fact is that my client doesnt want me to use because it we cant style them and it should be consistent with the entire application and product line. Also, regarding the examples I'm not allowed to use any external libraries, this restricts my hand from making any progress ahead. but your aria examples links educated me, thanks for that !

Comment: Glad those links were helpful! I totally understand wanting the app to look consistent, but being consistent with the user’s OS is also a good thing, as is accessibility. Hopefully, those two things combined will result in better retention or whatever other key metrics your client is focused on. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> 1.Open on Tab key press

Open on Tab key press of `ul` is a very bad solution because Tab key does various functions in the window as well. The dropdown toggle will become buggy as the focus has to be on the window. If you are using an `input` element like `select` then that's completely fine.

Still I have created a small mock-up using ONLY javascript as you are not allowed to use any external libraries. Created using `ul`.
Have a look at this fiddle : [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/598pdr28/)

**HTML :**

```
<div>
  <ul id="dropdown">
    <li class='highlight' data-key='A'><a href="#">America</a></li>
    <li data-key='B'><a href="#">Brazil</a></li>
    <li data-key='C'><a href="#">China</a></li>
    <li data-key='D'><a href="#">Denmark</a></li>
    <li data-key='E'><a href="#">Egypt</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
}

ul li.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

**Javascript :**

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownListener, false);

function keyDownListener(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode;
  var dropdwn = document.getElementById('dropdown');
  if (keyCode == 9) {
    dropdwn.style.display = (dropdwn.style.display != 'none' ? 'none' : 'block');
  } else if (dropdwn.style.display != 'none') {
    var items = dropdwn.getElementsByTagName("li");
    items[0].classList.remove("highlight");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
      var aKey = items[i].dataset.key;
      if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) === aKey) {
        for (var j = 0; j < items.length; ++j) {
          items[j].classList.remove("highlight");
        }
        items[i].classList.add("highlight");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Explanation :**

1. Add a `keydown` event listener on your document.
2. On press of `Tab` key show/ hide the dropdown.
3. On press of any other key, if the dropdown is visible check the `data-key` of each `li` and match it with the key pressed. If matches, highlight the respective list item.

And again a reminder, toggle of `ul` dropdown on `Tab` key press hurts accessibility. If it is a `select` dropdown then it's fine.

Comment: Hello There ! 
Thanks so much for your detailed explanation and solution.
I'd like to bring this to your notice that the fiddle doesnt work for some reason. Also keydown event listener looks like a plan but Im worried I have about 100 dropdowns spread across the application. I'm still trying to put li to work the way I wanted and let you know the progress.